# useDispatch in handleClick function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

How do I dispatch an action on button click? I want to dispatch an action that makes an async call. If this isn't possible, what's the practical way?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

import allActions from "../redux/actions/index";

import axios from "axios";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
}));

export default function ChatPreview({ chat }) {
  const [secondary, setSecondary] = React.useState(false);
  const lastMessageId = chat.messages.slice(-1)[0];
  const [message, setMessage] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const classes = useStyles();
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  const token = localStorage.getItem("IdToken").split(" ")[1];
  const dispatch = useDispatch;
  //Get otherUser
  let otherUser = {};
  chat.users.map((user_) => {
    if (user_.username !== user.username) otherUser = user_;
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    let headers = { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` };

    axios
      .get(`/messages/message/${lastMessageId}`, { headers })
      .then((res) => {
        setMessage(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setError(err);
      });
  }, []);

  let primary = false;
  if (user && message) {
    if (user._id === message.author) primary = true;
  }

  const handleClick = () => {
    dispatch(allActions.inboxActions.deleteChat(chat._id, token));
  };

  const chatPreviewMarkup =
    message && user ? (
      <List>
        <ListItem>
          <ListItemAvatar>
            <Avatar alt={otherUser.username} src={otherUser.avatar} />
          </ListItemAvatar>
          <ListItemText
            primary={
              primary ? (message.read ? "read" : "unread") : message.content
            }
            secondary={secondary ? "Secondary text" : null}
          />
          <ListItemSecondaryAction>
            <IconButton edge="end" aria-label="delete">
              <DeleteIcon onClick={handleClick} />
            </IconButton>
          </ListItemSecondaryAction>
        </ListItem>
      </List>
    ) : (
      <p>...loading</p>
    );

  return chatPreviewMarkup;
}
```

returns the following error:

Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Comment: `onClick` should receive a function reference, you're calling one instead of passing it. Change `onClick={handleClick()}` to `onClick={handleClick}`. If you still have problems you can update, but this appears to be the issue.

Comment: Also call the `useDispatch()` function.

Comment: I get an error when I try it that way.

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example then so we may see how and where the hook is called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `useDispatch()` outside of the callback because hooks must be at the top-level of the component.

You've **almost** done that, but you're getting thrown off by a typo. You need to change

```
const dispatch = useDispatch;
```

to

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
```

The missing parentheses mean that you aren't actually calling `useDispatch` until inside your `handleClick`.  The variable `dispatch` is the hook itself, not the return value, so when you call `dispatch(allActions...)` you're actually calling `useDispatch(allActions...)` and getting an error.

Answer (score 4):

Like this

```
function MyComponent() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const handleClick = () => {
    dispatch(actionCreator())
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick}>
      Click me
    </button>
  )
}
```